# table not getting created

Tags: android

I have written for tables creation but when i am trying to access the table from one of my screen its throwing exception .

Even when i went do shell in commannd prompt i was not able to find that table . Any clue that i need to do .

logs :

```
W/System.err(  275):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
I/Database(  275): sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg = no such table: woman_registration
D/AndroidRuntime(  275): Shutting down VM
W/dalvikvm(  275): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
E/AndroidRuntime(  275): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(  275): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: woman_registration: , while compiling: SELECT DISTINCT
 * FROM woman_registration WHERE  (m_name = ? AND  f_name = ? and m_age_range = ?)
E/AndroidRuntime(  275):        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.native_compile(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(  275):        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.compile(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:91)
E/AndroidRuntime(  275):        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.<init>(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:64)
E/AndroidRuntime(  275):        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:80)
E/AndroidRuntime(  275):        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:46)
E/AndroidRuntime(  275):        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:42)
E/AndroidRuntime(  275):        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1345)
E/AndroidRuntime(  275):        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.queryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1229)
E/AndroidRuntime(  275):        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1184)
E/AndroidRuntime(  275):        at org.atl.db.DBAdapter.isWomanAlreadyRegisgtered(DBAdapter.java:376)
E/AndroidRuntime(  275):        at com.accenturelabs.idoc.RegisterWoman.registerMother(RegisterWoman.java:237)
E/AndroidRuntime(  275):        at com.accenturelabs.idoc.RegisterWoman.access$1(RegisterWoman.java:223)
E/AndroidRuntime(  275):        at com.accenturelabs.idoc.RegisterWoman$4.onClick(RegisterWoman.java:141)
E/AndroidRuntime(  275):        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
E/AndroidRuntime(  275):        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
E/AndroidRuntime(  275):        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
E/AndroidRuntime(  275):        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
E/AndroidRuntime(  275):        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
E/AndroidRuntime(  275):        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
E/AndroidRuntime(  275):        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(  275):        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
E/AndroidRuntime(  275):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
E/AndroidRuntime(  275):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
E/AndroidRuntime(  275):        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
D/dalvikvm(   58): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 18388 objects / 947880 bytes in 106ms
W/ActivityManager(   58):   Force finishing activity com.accenturelabs.idoc/.RegisterWoman
I/ARMAssembler(   58): generated scanline__00000077:03515104_00000000_00000000 [ 33 ipp] (47 ins) at [0x34d7b0:0x34d86c] in 7148901 ns
```

Comment: @bhalkian Try to  drop all your tables or delete the .db file from FileExplorer data->data->your package Name->databases and once again create launch your application. May be your db file must have already created with some tables less in your emulator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually i had to uninstall the application from the emulator .it worked fine after that

Comment: Remember If first time you run you app and then you modify your db then you have to uninstall it and then re install it. else database will not going to update.

Answer (score 0):

Try to chek from your ddms data -> data -> your package ->database
here you will find that table is created of not.
also it you pull it out and open with SQllite browser u will get all the table list in it.

Hope this will help you

Comment: actually the same code ran on the device but when i am trying on my emulator it not working at all.

Answer (score 0):

You should be extending `SQLiteOpenHelper` for your database code if you are not already.

Then check that your onUpgrade() method also calls back to your onCreate() method. You may be dropping all your tables and then not re-creating them. Make sure you bump the database version number every time you make a change to your tables.

The google iosched app has a complete, if not slightly complex example of how to do this.

http://code.google.com/p/iosched/source/browse/android/src/com/google/android/apps/iosched/provider/ScheduleDatabase.java